# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable' in google Colaboratory

Tags: python, tensorflow, variables, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to create a variable tensor in google Collaboratory with this code, but error because TensorFlow doesn't have a module about variables. what's the solution?

```
import tensorflow as tf
var_1 = tf.variable(tf.ones([2,3]))
```

Error:

````
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-2-2666f49bf801> in <module>()
    ----> 1 var_1 = tf.variable(tf.ones([2,3]))```
    
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'variable'
````

Comment: The solution is to capitalize properly. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable

Comment: It is `Variable` not `variable`. V in capital.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error. Use capital letter V for Variable.

You can refer below code for the same.

```
import tensorflow as tf

var_1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2,3]))

var_1
```

Click [here,](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) for more details